# REST service testing READY API -- Multiple attachment with multipart data issue

Tags: rest, soapui, multipartform-data, ready-api

I am doing testing of REST API POST Call for multipart data through Ready API. I  have attached multiple images in Attachments TAB for my test suite . But sending only one of them in parameter.
While hitting the service Request, RAW Tab shows the correct file name but some how READY API is picking all the attachments in data as i am getting file size limit issue from the rest API.

See the attachments for the REST Call

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jMuo.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdsIO.png

Comment: Further down on your Raw tab I suspect you'll see it's also trying to send the other two images. Is that the case? If you don't want to send those images, why have them as attachments?

Comment: Actually DataSource step in Ready API has case that will run my suite with different images involved in test steps. I mean all the images are involved with some scenario.